# request parameter in a Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I made a cloud page in MC that allows me to update some field in SC

```
>   %%[ if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then ]%%
>          <p style="text-align:center; color: #000000; font-family: Arial, sans-serif ; font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">Dziękujemy!</p> 
> <p style="text-align:center; color: #000000; font-family: Arial,
> sans-serif ;font-size:14px;"> Zmiany zostały zapisane. </p>
>       %%[ else ]%%     
>       <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">   <div>
>           <label align="center" for="scales">Jesteś pewien, że chcesz zrezygnować z otrzymywania od nas wiadomości?</label><br>  
>       <div> <input type="radio" id="NIE" name="Optin" value="False">
>           <label for="NIE">NIE</label> </div>
>       <div><input type="radio" id="TAK" name="Optin" value="True">
>           <label for="TAK">TAK</label></div>                  </div><br><br>
>          <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true" />
>          <input type="submit" value="POTWIERDŹ">
>       </form>
>       %%[ endif ]%%   </fieldset>    </div>    </tr></table></div>
>     %%[ Set @Id= '00Q9E000005akYkUAI'
> 
> if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then  
> UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead",@Id,"OptInEmail__c", False,
> "OptInSMS__c", False) 
> endif   ]%%
```

and when I run the page and click on the button I have a server error(500 - Internal server error.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes certainly from the `UpdateDE` function.

Fist of all, you need to use `UpdateData` instead of `UpdateDE`. `UpdateDE` only works in an email send while `UpdateData` is used with landing pages and SMS messages

The first parameter of the `UpdateDE` stands for the number of columns used to build WHERE clause. And since you are using one field to do the where, you need to use something like:

```
UpdateData("DE_Lead_PL", 1, "Id", @Id,"OptInEmail", False, "OptInSMS", False)
```

**Update:**

Your problem can be related to the `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` function. You need to check that you have the permission to update data on Leads on your Sales/Service Cloud org.

Also, you need to take a look at validation rules (if there are any) on `OptInEmail__c` and `OptInSMS__c` fields.

And since you are using a hardcoded lead's id, I assume the lead exists. However, I would recommend checking if the lead exists before calling `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject`.

You can use something like:

```
SET @LookUpLeads = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead', 'Id', 'Id', '=', '00Q9E000005akYkUAI')
 IF RowCount(@LookUpLeads) > 0 then
  UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Lead",@Id,"OptInEmail__c", 'false',"OptInSMS__c", 'false') 
ENDIF
```

Comment: thank you for your help it was an error the updateDE doesn't belong to this page i remove it but still have the same issue 
thank you

Comment: Okey, I've updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your help I'll try your code
the ID I use is just for testing after the page work I'm not using a hardcoded ID
I keep you in touch when I finish the test

Comment: Hello i try the solution but it still doesn't work and in SC there is no call in the logs